# n Time Ago in MVC Razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, date, if-statement, razor, time

How to do a Time Ago function in MVC Razor?

I'm working on a Announcement function that display not only the date the announcement first announced, but also **how long ago** that the announcement first announced.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [asp.net mvc time ago in words helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301609/asp-net-mvc-time-ago-in-words-helper)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate relative time in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11/calculate-relative-time-in-c-sharp)